# How to implement structured data on AJAX site for SEO?

Tags: ajax, seo, json-ld, structured-data

We are having a site that all data is loaded via javascript, which I call AJAX site, SEO is the current big task, I ended up with my own solution after several days searching through web: https://github.com/liuwenchao/ajax-seo, but now I'm blocked by structured data: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/?hl=en&rd=1, As it's not needed for end user, I'd like a solution that works like my own solution that provide such info to crawlers only.

Question: Is it possible to generate JSON-LD information in the page to crawlers only?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible but not encouraged. You should serve search engines the same "data" you serve to users. Anything else might be interpreted as trying to cheat and could in consequence lead to lower rankings.